# I expect the code below to get data of donors base on the BLOOG GROUP & RHESUS i entered, but it is fetching everything from data base instead

Tags: mysql, json, flutter, get, fetch

I expect the code below to get data of donors base on the BLOOG GROUP & RHESUS I  entered, but it is fetching everything from data base instead what needed.

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("SEARCH", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0)),
                ],
              )),

          onPressed: () {
            if (bloodtype == 'blood' && rhesustype == 'rhesus') {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: new Text('No available donor...'),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        //FlatButton
                        TextButton(
                            child: new Text("OK"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            })
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            } else {
              getData();
            }
          },
```

Comment: Could you please provide your expected output as well as the output you are getting?

Comment: the expected output should be that the getData () method should fetch and display only information of donors base on the blood group i entered. instead when i click on search, it is fetching everything from the database